# Applying blur shader causing blur to an image when a transparent image overlays it

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, shader, xna-4.0

I'm trying to make an image blur when a transparent image overlays it, I am wanting it only to blur the section that is being overlayed. So if half of the original image is not being overlapped, that half is not blurred but the rest is.

Un-blurred - Not overlapping 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/joKzu.png

Fully Blurred - partially overlapping
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8Tb7.png

Game1.cs

```
namespace NewShaderTutorial
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Effect blur;
        Texture2D surge;
        Rectangle surgeRectangle;
        Texture2D bubble;
        Rectangle bubbleRectangle;
        private bool overlapping;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            surge = Content.Load<Texture2D>("surge");
            surgeRectangle = new Rectangle(250, 250, surge.Width, surge.Height);

            bubble = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Bubble - Red");
            bubbleRectangle = new Rectangle(250, 250, bubble.Width, bubble.Height);

            blur = Content.Load<Effect>("blur");

            // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                bubbleRectangle.X--;
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                bubbleRectangle.X++;
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                bubbleRectangle.Y--;
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                bubbleRectangle.Y++;

            blur.Parameters["blur"].SetValue(0.015f);

            Overlapping();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            if (overlapping == true)
            {

                spriteBatch.Begin(0, null, null, null, null, blur);
                spriteBatch.Draw(surge, surgeRectangle, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
                //     spriteBatch.Begin(0, null, null, null, null, blur);
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.Draw(bubble, bubbleRectangle, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
            }
            else
            {
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                spriteBatch.Draw(surge, surgeRectangle, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.Draw(bubble, bubbleRectangle, Color.White);
                spriteBatch.End();
            }

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        public void Overlapping()
        {
            float surgeDimensionX = surgeRectangle.X + surge.Width;
            float surgeDimensionY = surgeRectangle.Y + surge.Height;
            float bubbleDimensionX = bubbleRectangle.X + bubble.Width;
            float bubbleDimensionY = bubbleRectangle.Y + bubble.Height;

            if ((surgeRectangle.X >= (bubbleRectangle.X) && ((surgeRectangle.X <= (bubbleDimensionX))) && (surgeRectangle.Y >= (bubbleRectangle.Y)) && (surgeRectangle.Y <= (bubbleDimensionY))))
            {
                overlapping = true;
            }
            else
            {
                overlapping = false;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(overlapping);
        }
    }
}
```

Shader Class

```
 float4x4 World; 
    float4x4 View; 
    float4x4 Projection; 

    // TODO: add effect parameters here. 
    sampler TextureSampler; 

    float blur = 0.0015; 

    struct PixelInput 
    { 
        float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD0; 
    }; 

float4 PixelShaderFunction(PixelInput input) : COLOR0 
{ 

        float4 color = tex2D(TextureSampler, 
        float2(input.TexCoord.x+blur, input.TexCoord.y+blur)); 
    color += tex2D( TextureSampler, 
        float2(input.TexCoord.x-blur, input.TexCoord.y-blur)); 
    color += tex2D( TextureSampler, 
        float2(input.TexCoord.x+blur, input.TexCoord.y-blur)); 
    color += tex2D( TextureSampler, 
        float2(input.TexCoord.x-blur, input.TexCoord.y+blur)); 

    color = color / 4; 
        return color; 
} 


    technique Default 
    { 
        pass P0 
        { 
            // TODO: set renderstates here. 

            PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction(); 
        } 
    }
```

So I'm wanting to get the partially overlapping part to only blur the section that is being overlapped not the whole sprite. Any help or direction to solve this would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That´s quite a wrong approach you have there, you simply either blur everything or nothing.

You can do for example following: Render your background, character, etc. Without shader into offscreen Render target, resolve that render target (by switching RT back to null - backbuffer), render it full screen and then render your bubble with blur shader, send your existing render target of content behind bubble to shader (to it´s second texture sampler). You will also need viewport width and height. Now project your render target according to vertex position into pixel shader, combine it with your bubble texture and clip or Discard pixels outside circle, either clip it by alpha (if only pixels outside circle got for example color.a = 0; or make mask for that circle in another sampler used by that shader and clip it by that.

Discard https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb943995%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Clip https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Clip is preferred.